# How to avoid using conda-forge packages unless necessary?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I'm running into a minor but annoying issue with conda when installing individual packages from conda-forge.  Typically I'd run something like this:

`conda install -c conda-forge somepackage`

This has the effect of frequently updating other packages using conda-forge: almost always ca-certificates, certifi and openssl; and sometimes major packages like python, numpy etc (all from conda-forge).  I suspect these updates are not strictly necessary; those packages get pulled in using some logic along the lines of "in order to install the latest version of somepackage I need python>=3.8 but the current python is 3.7; I can use conda-forge, so I'll get the latest python from conda-forge which is newer than the one in default".

What I would like to accomplish is: install *any* version of somepackage (not necessarily latest) while installing *as little as possible* from conda-forge.  In particular, if there is a choice between keeping an already installed package and upgrading, I always want to keep; and if there is a choice between default channel and conda-forge, I always want default (even if those choices result in ending up with older versions of the new packages I'm trying to install, and/or their new dependencies - but not if they result in the install being impossible).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: this might be helpful https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html

Comment: @jacub it is very helpful, but I think it doesn't seem to completely solve this.  1. when using a channel with -c (rather than conda config --append channels etc), where does it go in the list? and 2. how would channel priority allow a scenario such as "use higher version package from lower priority channel, but only if it is needed to install the requested package at all (rather than the latest version of the requested package)"

Comment: @jacub probably the best thing for me is to use channel_priority=strict and the default channel first (although it seems that may sometimes make installs fail that may otherwise succeed).  another issue though, how do I tell conda "don't upgrade dependencies" (regardless of channel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ## how do I tell conda "don't upgrade dependencies"

One can use `conda install --freeze-installed PACKAGE...` ([documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Solver%20Mode%20Modifiers)) to prevent conda from updating packages that are already installed. This does not, however, seem to prevent updating of packages under the `aggressive_update_packages` key of conda's config. The default packages there are `ca-certificates`, `certifi`, and `openssl` (see the [default configuration](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html)). One can check their own configuration with

```
conda config --show aggressive_update_packages
```

> ## install any version of somepackage (not necessarily latest) while installing as little as possible from conda-forge

According to [the conda documentation on managing channels](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html), one can do this by putting the `conda-forge` channel at the bottom of the list of channels and setting `channel_priority: strict` in conda's config.

> With strict channel priority, packages in lower priority channels are not considered if a package with the same name appears in a higher priority channel.

The "manage channels" page recommends setting strict as the default and indicates that conda 5.x will set strict as the default value for `channel_priority`.

One can write the following to their `~/.condarc` file:

```
channel_priority: strict
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
```

However, if one uses the `-c/--channel` option in `conda config`, that channel will take precedence over any other channels. So if one sets their conda config as above but uses `conda install -c conda-forge numpy`, then `numpy` will be installed from `conda-forge`.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, I endorse the conclusion in [@jakub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65494330/570918): Define a reasonable global channel priority and try to avoid using *ad hoc* specifications via the `--channel|-c` argument.

There are some additional options that may be worth pointing out:

1. Specify that a particular package should come from a given channel with

   ```
    conda install conda-forge::somepackage
   ```

   and this will not change the channel priority.
2. Explicitly list channel priorities in the `install` command:

   ```
    conda install -c defaults -c conda-forge somepackage
   ```

   which puts **defaults** with top priority.
3. Define and manipulate environments through YAML files. YAMLs include a channels section, so you can be explicit about the priority. If you require a new package in the environment, it can be added to the YAML - let's say `env.yaml` - and that edit can be transferred to the environment with

   ```
    conda env update -f env.yaml
   ```